# Django model instance getattr in multiple database landscape

Tags: django, database

I have multiple database landscape with `"default": {}` in databases. I dont need any default db and made this for consistency as suggested in django docs.

Database settings is set like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {},
    'mydb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        ...
    },
    'mydb2': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        ...
        }
    }
```

I also have some `Model1` which has related `Model2` by FK, like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    related_field = models.ForeignKey( 
        "Model2",
        db_index=True, 
        null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now i am struggling with strange behaviour: having instance of Model1 in one of the databases, i want to get it related instance from Model2, i use:

```
inst1 = Model1.objects.using("mydb").get(...) # this sets inst1._state.db to "mydb
related = getattr(inst1, "related_field")
```

and get `ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

So instead of respecting `inst1._state.db` underlying ForwardManyToOneDescriptor().`__get__` method inits manager with "default" database which leads to this exception.

My ugly workaround trying to make generic function for this is:

```
from django.apps import apps

related_model = apps.get_model(inst1._meta.app_label, inst1._meta.model_name)
related_object = related_model.objects.using(inst1._state.db).get(...)
```

Is there any way to make getattr(instance, relatedFK) pay attention to instance._state_db?

Comment: Can you please update your question with relevant settings file content ?

Comment: addede databases info

Answer (score 0):

The DATABASES setting **must configure a default database**; any number of additional databases may also be specified.

We must provide a default database, so you can do something like this :

```
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    ...
  },
  'mydb': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    ...
  },
  'mydb2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    ...
  }
}
```

Reference : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

Comment: Sorry but it is not "a must" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/.  "Django requires that a default database entry be defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will not be used"

Comment: Sorry my bad, I assumed you're using 2.0